# How to write a regular expression in Python that accepts alphabets, numbers and a few selected special characters(,.-|;!_?)?

Tags: python, pyramid, colander

A Regular Expression in Python that accepts letters,numbers and only these special characters (,.-|;!_?).

I have tried solving the problem through the following regular expressions but it didn't work:

```
'([a-zA-Z0-9,.-|;!_?])$'
'([a-zA-Z0-9][.-|;!_?])$'
```

Can someone please help me write the regular expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following should work (tested on RegExr against `Foo123,.-|;!_?`):

```
^[\w,.\-|;!_?]*$
```

In your regular expressions, you forget to escape the '-' character, which is interpreted as a range of characters to match against.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (you should escape `-` like this `\-`):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9,.\-|;!_?]+$
```

`+` to prevent matching empty strings, to allow them, you can use `*` instead.

**Examples:**

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9,.\-|;!_?]+$', '12.0')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000027EB850>
>>> re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9,.\-|;!_?]+$', '')
>>>
>>> re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9,.\-|;!_?]+$', 'test!?')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000027EB7E8>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this for only one character:

```
'[a-zA-Z0-9,.\-|;!_?]' or '[\w,.\-|;!_?]'
```

Use this for all characters:

```
'[a-zA-Z0-9,.\-|;!_?]*' or '[\w,.\-|;!_?]*'
```

Use this for an equal check:

```
'^[a-zA-Z0-9,.\-|;!_?]*$' or '^[\w,.\-|;!_?]*$'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\w` (bonus: unicode and locale support!):

> matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the set [a-zA-Z0-9_]

See [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). Also, you might want to use a raw string when specifying your regular expression pattern:

```
m = re.match(r'[\w,.-|;!?]+', your_string)
```

Notice the use of `+` (repeat once or more). You also used `$` to match the end of the string but I did not include it in mine. YMMV.